# Comparing two JSON to make sure Key of first json is present in other one

Tags: java, json, templates, sms

I am writing here to get some clue regarding the problem I'm facing.

I am actually writing a service that will send text messages using some third party API. I've lots of message templates (static text and placeholders for dynamic content) that needs to be sent out and this service will be called from multiple modules with-in my application.

What I've planned is to store message templates in database and once any module require to send text message it will call my messaging service and pass data require to fill up the placeholders for a particular template.

I am saving my templates in database as follows:

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "[GREETING], this is the test message sent on [DATE].",
        "constant1": "",
        "constant2": ""
    },
    "metadata": {
        "data": {
            "message": {
                "[GREETING]": "required",
                "[DATE]": "required"
            },
            "constant1": "required",
            "constant2": "required",
            "constant3": "optional"
        }
    }
}
```

**data** is the actual object I want eventually to pass messaging api and metadata is basically the constants and variables that are required/optional to complete **data** object.

and the data I'm receiving from other modules that are calling my service is:

```
{
    "[GREETING]": "Dear John Doe",
    "[DATE]": "28 February",
    "data": {
        "constant1": 982042,
        "constant2": [64238, 64239]
    }
}
```

So the issue is, I've to verify that all the required constant that are set required in templates metadata should be present the the json I'm receiving while my service is being called. I'm bit confused here of how I can compare the keys of data with template to make sure all the required data of template is sent by the module that has just called my service.

Can someone give me a clue if it's even possible in java ?

p.s: I just want some guidance or clue.

Thanks

**Update:** if someone have better and neat suggestion in achieving what I want to achieve in above mentioned scenario, please share I would really appreciate that.

**Update2:** Clarification of what I actually want to achieve: I've a JSON template in which I have a metadata field that tells me which parameters are required to fill up this specific template. So upon receiving call to my service, I've to first check that required parameters (set in metadata of templates) should be there in API request body. Hope that clears my requirements now.

Comment: You start by *parsing* the JSON. Comparing raw JSON text will be insanely difficult, because different text may still be same values, e.g. the data could be `{"\u005BGREETING\u005D":"Dear John Doe","\u005BDATE\u005D":"28 February","data":{"constant1":982042,"constant2":[64238,64239]}}`. Different raw text, but same JSON data.

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm little confused of what you have said above. Is there a way I could compare ?

Comment: A way? Sure. But why work through all those headaches, when parsing using a third-party library is so dang easy? Do you really care whether there is a space after colon or whether `[` is given as `\u005B` or `[`, or is it really the data you want to compare?

Comment: Actually what I want to achieve is, I've a JSON template in which I have a metadata field that tells me which parameters are required to fill up this specific template. So upon receiving call to my service, I've to first check that required parameters (set in metadata of templates) should be there in API request body. Hope that clears my requirements now.

Comment: Yeah, for that too, you should simply parse the JSON, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: yeah I ended up with this solution. :) Thanks for your time though.